# How can I print Qt:HANDLE on linux? (Qt5)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt5, qdebug

As a means to verify which thread my code is actually running under I use [QThread::currentThreadId()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#currentThreadId). However the [Qt::HANDLE](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#HANDLE-typedef) type that is returned from this function is according to the documentation a platform dependant typedef. On my platform (Linux) it was simply a typedef for `void *` (typeless pointer).

So how would I go about printing this using for example `qDebug()`, and how about converting it to a `QString`?

Comment: You could just dump `QThread::currentThread`, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this myself with the following two helping functions. Note that I opted for using `void *` as the type instead of `Qt::HANDLE` as this might be useful in other cases and other platforms as well.

```
// Allow Qt::HANDLE and void * to be streamed to QDebug for easier threads debugging
QDebug operator <<(QDebug d, void *p){
    d.nospace() << QString::number((long long)p, 16);
    return d.space();
}

// Allow Qt::HANDLE and void * to be added together with QString objects for easier threads debugging
const QString operator+ ( const QString &s, void *p ){
    return (s+ QString::number((long long)p, 16));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer this way, maybe you create a qstring variable and then you can print it even setText() by using this qstring variable for some widgets.

```cpp
QString id=QString( "%1" ).arg(static_cast<int>(QThread::currentThreadId()), 16);
ui->user->setText(id);
this->setWindowTitle(id);
```

Comment: Hi! I was explicitly looking for how to print the handle with qDebug(), but your solution is definitely useful for converting to QString! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)